# Prometheus error: write to WAL: log samples: write /data/wal/xxxxx: read-only file system

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks

I have an AKS managed cluster in which I installed Prometheus (v2.16.0). All of my targets are down because of this error: `level=warn ts=2020-09-01T14:05:04.171Z caller=scrape.go:987 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes-nodes target=https://kubernetes.default.svc:443/api/v1/nodes/xxxxx/proxy/metrics msg="appending scrape report failed" err="write to WAL: log samples: write /data/wal/XXXXXX: read-only file system"`
I have multiple AKS clusters that have Prometheus installed, only this one has that error. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: Restarting prometheus fixed the problem, but it might occur again in the future.

Comment: Can you exec to container and create a file in `/data/wal/XXXXXX` path? Can you explain how you deployed promethus (helm chart, custom deployment, preferably add source code so its easier to replicate)? @Daniel

Comment: @Matt I used a helm chart to install Prometheus. I tried to exec to the container and I can't even see the ```/data``` folder.

Comment: Can you provide the exact chart you used? @Daniel

Comment: I used stable/prometheus with a few custom values. I set ```storage.tsdb.retention.time``` to ```15d```, ```storage.tsdb.retention.size``` to ```6GB``` and ```server.persistentVolume.size``` to ```16Gi```

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was tainting the node then rolling the Prometheus pod to a new node. It was a disk issue of the AKS that if you checked the condition of the node, it would say `ReadonlyFilesystem`.